# Exchange Server Not Receiving Magento 1.9.0 Transactional Emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional

We have Magento CE 1.9.0 running on CENTOS 6.5 x86_64, with Apache 2.4/PHP 5.  I have an issue where my exchange server is not receiving any transactional email from my Magento box.

I do receive transactional emails to @hotmail.com, @yahoo.com and @gmail.com but not to my Exchange server corporate account.

SPF record looks good.

Any tips would help.

Comment: Nothing in my junk/spam folder on the exchange server mail.  For gmail.com, hotmail.com and yahoo.com, every email comes through without a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SPF I have found it incredibly helpful to install DomainKeys, DKIM.

Additionally it may be advisable to go with a hosted SMTP provider, like Mailgun or Socketlabs, which will not only provide higher deliverability for you they will help you improve it over time.

Answer (score 0):

If other email providers are receiving the email but not your Exchange server, this is more of an issue with the email service and not related to Magento itself.

You will need to have someone check your server log to see if the emails are successfully delivered to determine whether the issue lies in the sender or receiver.

If the issue lies with the sender, you may want to consider a third-party transactional email provider like Mandrill (they provide 12,000 Free emails per month).

**UPDATE (JULY 28, 2016):** Mandrill stopped offering their free service but there are still other providers offering similar service, like SendGrid and Mailgun.